# ¿Descargar varios archivos desde laravel php?

Tags: php, laravel

Cordial saludo compañeros, tengo la siguiente duda, estoy desarrollando una aplicación en laravel php, la cual debe exportar un archivo word y excel después de realizar ciertos procesos, mi problema es al momento de descargar estos archivos, ya que necesito que descarguen ambos al presionar un botón, estoy usando la sentencia return response()->download('cot1.docx'), el problema es que al usarlo dos veces, solo tomara el primer return y descargara el primer archivo, el otro no lo tomara mi código es el siguiente:

Para el word

```
$TemplateProcessor= new TemplateProcessor(Storage_path('Estudio_conexion.docx'));


// $TemplateProcessor->setValue('var',$saludo);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('algoo',$definicion);

$TemplateProcessor->setValue('nombre_cliente' ,$nombre_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('nombre_empresa' ,$empresa_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('Correo',$correo_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('direccion',$direccion_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('fecha',$fecha_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('referencia',$referencia_);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('objetivo',$objetivo_);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('nom_est',$nombre_proyecto);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('precio_est','$'.($precio_est2));
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('precio_iva','$'.$precio_iva2);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('total','$'.($total2));
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('acti1',$act1);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('acti2',$act2);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('mtdg' ,$desc_met);
// $TemplateProcessor->setValue('firma',$firma);

//Guardamos el documento y lo retornamos como descarga
$TemplateProcessor->saveAs('cot1.docx');

 return response()->download('cot1.docx');
```

Para el excel:

```
/Abrimos la plantilla
$sheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load(Storage_path('cotizacion_excel.xlsx'));

$sheet->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$activeSheetacti=$sheet->getActiveSheet();
$activeSheetacti->setCellValue('A1',$nombre_proyecto);
$activeSheetacti->setCellValue('A2',$empresa_cli);
$activeSheetacti->setCellValue('A3',$fecha_cli);
//Creamos el writer 
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($sheet);

//Guardamos la copia de la plantilla con los datos personaizados
$writer->save($empresa_cli.'_Cot_Rev0.xlsx');

//Se descarga la plantilla
return response()->download($empresa_cli.'_Cot_Rev0.xlsx');
```

Todo esto se encuentra en la misma funcion, ya que ambas plantillas reciben los datos por el mismo formulario.
Intente descargar ambos archivos con un solo return de esta manera:

```
return Response()->download(["cot1.docx","$empresa_cli.'_Cot_Rev0.xlsx"]);
```

Pero no funciona de esa manera, podrian darme alguna idea de como descargar ambos archivos por el navegador, teniendo en cuenta que ambos estan en la misma funcion?

Comment: tendras que armar multiples request via javascript o empaquetarlos en un zip https://stackoverflow.com/a/36675577/1423096 en algunos navegadores podes enviarlos usando mime/multipart pero no es muy consistente

Comment: Listo, aplique lo del archivo zip, no es lo que buscaba, pero como solucion al problema funciona, Muchas gracias.